# Programatically modify tag visibility, order

Tags: macos, finder, automation, preferences, finder-tag

I need to programatically alter both the visibility and default sort order for tags, explicitly in Catalina: I have different categories of tags that, depending on what project I'm working on, I'd like to show and hide in the Finder sidebar en bloc (i.e. 'food: xxx' or 'font: xxx').

I'm familiar with the command-line `tag` utility and Leap's apps; neither seem to offer the option to modify visibility or sort order.

the dictionary in com.apple.finder.plist appears to list them in display order, and the <

> attribute seems to indicate visibility, but the file warns:

```
//
// The pretty-printed property list below has been created
// from a binary version on disk and should not be saved as
// the ASCII format is a subset of the binary representation!
//
```

The target data is represented in binary form in `values[:FinderTagDict][:remotevalue]` - but it's unclear if that is the ultimate repository for the properties, or if that's just part of the pretty-printed attributes.

Will updating `values[:FinderTagDict][:remotevalue]` in `com.apple.finder.plist` be sufficient to update finder preferences?   Or is there another layer of abstraction that needs to be addressed?

Alternately, is there some other class tucked away that manages `kMDItemUserTags` attributes?

For the time being, modifying visibility and order is the primary use case.  The non-resizable, no-filter preferences pane just is not cutting it.

(fifth time I've tried to find an answer to this, if there are any resources out there I'm just not finding them.)

Comment: looking at com.apple.finder.plist, I am not seeing what you're seeing. No `FinderTagDict` or `remoteValue` listings. Can you explain precisely how you got that result?

Comment: I'm looking at ~/Library/SyncedPreferences/com.apple.finder.plist .

Comment: Hm. Well, SyncedPreferences is used for device syncing. poking around a little, I suspect that the primary info is stored in `~/Library/Application Support/Knowledge/KnowledgeC.db`, which is an sqlite database that seems to store spotlight metadata. I **would not** try to modify that db directly, even if you're an sqlite pro; consequences could be dire. but there may be a way to access it through metadata utilities.  I'll look a little further.

Comment: Well, I don't see any hooks for setting for reordering the tag sort order or visibility. Can you explain your larger goal? maybe there's a different way to achieve it.

Comment: I have a system that classifies images based on content type (photo v infographic v illustration v painting) + subject for folksonomy, plus font mgmt, plus 3d models, plus... 
  The immediate goal is to make enabling/disabling tags en bloc to control what show up in the sidebar, for a modal interface - the built-in tag manager can't be made full-screen, no search/sort, etc.

Comment: and by system, I mean tensorflow classifier that does the above, and another one that classifies fonts for style, family, x-height, etc.  thousands of tags, different work modes need diff. ones visible for drag+drop.  eventually i'd like to move towards tag-based visualization for accessing files instead of hierarchical navigation, graph networks that show other tag associations.... but I need this first.

Comment: Ok, I followed that, mostly (you lost me at ' tensorflow classifier'). I'll look some more because... you know, covid... but let me ask you this. Have you looked into 'Smart Folders'/'Saved Searches'? These two things (which amount to basically the same thing) are spotlight searches that present themselves as standard finder windows: they'll gather every file that meets criteria across a specified file structure and show them like they were all in the same folder, allowing sorting, filtering, drag&drop. You can put them in the sidebar or leave them in a file...

Comment: Yup, I've used those extensively too.  Problem is, some things I tag manually and want to be able to drag/drop files onto appropriate tags in the sidebar (i.e. emoji tags for <3, stars) or other content-related stuff.  hard to fit in 500char :)

Comment: current example: working on a design for an artificial muscle fiber powered ventilator sleeve for emergency use in rural hospitals for Cov19.  as I acquire assorted stl files for diff parts of the process, i want my 3d-related and project-related tags to be visible in the sidebar to manually classify them with min clicks.  occasionally, OSX resorts them on its own, and without any sort fn or window resizing optn in Finder preferences, manually finding/sorting/etc. those tags is nigh impossible.

Comment: Ok, so it seems to me that the *core* of your problem is efficient tagging: you want the tags you are currently working with to be easily available in the sidebar so that you can quickly tag the files you are working on. If that's not correct, let me know, otherwise give me a bit to work on it.

Comment: Well, kind of.... it's more of a tag management issue  Ultimately, batch editing of tags and metadata - bulk rename w/regex, sort order, enable/disable, etc.  What I'd really like is to be able to build a finder preferences interface that works, with the ability to create what i'd consider tag supercategories that don't all have the same prefix.  Can you think of a reason Apple might want to obfuscate this functionality?

Comment: I don't think Apple is obfuscating. The Finder is just an *old* core app that's been Frankensteined to death; 'tags' are added functionality grafted on to an app that was never really meant to be extensible. There are a few Finder replacement apps out there  (PathFinder, ForkLift, XFile), but I don't know much about them.

Comment: Part of the problem I'm having with your question is that you're not always clear when you're talking about tags as they relate to *individual files*, and tags when they relate to  *system prefs*. The manipulation of tags on files is comparatively easy (that's file metadata in extended attributes); the manipulation of system preferences (the names and ordering of tag labels system-wide) has no easy access point, probably because no one at Apple thought anyone would need an access point.

Comment: Of course, it would be fairly trivial to write an app that would allow tag management *within its context*; the hard part is mirroring it back to the system.  If you just want an app that does its own tagging and classification of files, ok (check the app store, there might be one already).  If you're trying to manipulate the files as they appear in the Finder, that's a bit harder.

Comment: I think I have a handle on the problem, if not the solution. There's a core service called 'cfprefsd' (core foundation prefs daemon) that caches app preferences in RAM so that apps can look them up faster. It caches them persistently, so that the system hardly ever looks at the actual plist files. Normally we would cope with that by using the `defaults` utility (which works in tandem with cfprefsd), but because the SharedPreferences plists aren't part of the defaults 'domain' system, that does not seem to work.

Comment: Basically, the Finder has these settings held in RAM, and there's no way I see to clear them or override them, except through the Finder interface. It just keeps writing them back out from memory. Even the core foundation routines seem to be dependent on the 'domain' system — file paths don't seem to register — so it's just insufferably stuck.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a partial solution that might serve until I can see something more effective. Instead of trying to track down the correct place to modify the Finder settings under the hood — which is surprisingly difficult — this GUI-scripts the Finder to turn on only those tags you want to use at a given moment. The script presents you with a token field, where you enter the names of the tags you want activated (commas and returns are the separation characters), then it opens the Finder preferences window, loops through all the items in the table view, and clicks them on or off as needed so you'll only see the ones you want. It's slow and occasionally throws an error (typical of GUI scripting) but it gets the job done.

---

- *Script updated 11/29/20 with trap some GUI synchronization issues..*

---

```
global click_error_depth, seek_error_depth

set {click_error_depth, seek_error_depth} to {0, 0}

set tag_string to text returned of (display dialog "Enter a list of tags" default answer "")
set tid to my text item delimiters
set my text item delimiters to {",  ", ", ", ","}
set tag_list to text items of tag_string
set my text item delimiters to tid

tell application "Finder"
    open window of Finder preferences
    tell Finder preferences
        tell its window
            set (current panel) to Label Preferences panel
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
tell application "System Events"
    tell process "Finder"
        tell window "Finder Preferences"
            tell first scroll area's first table
                with timeout of 3600 seconds
                    set curretly_tagged to first checkbox of first UI element of (every row whose first UI element's first checkbox's value is 1)
                end timeout
                repeat with this_checkbox in curretly_tagged
                    my clickErrorTrap(this_checkbox)
                end repeat
                repeat with a_tag in tag_list
                    set target_checkbox to my seekErrorTrap(a_tag)
                    if class of target_checkbox is checkbox then
                        my clickErrorTrap(target_checkbox)
                    end if
                end repeat
            end tell
        end tell
    end tell
end tell
tell application "Finder"
    tell Finder preferences
        tell its window
            close
        end tell
    end tell
end tell

on clickErrorTrap(a_checkbox)
    try
        tell application "System Events"
            tell a_checkbox
                click
            end tell
        end tell
        return true
    on error
        if click_error_depth < 10 then
            set click_error_depth to click_error_depth + 1
            delay 0.1
            set flag to clickErrorTrap(a_checkbox)
        else
            return false
        end if
        set click_error_depth to click_error_depth - 1
        return flag
    end try
end clickErrorTrap

on seekErrorTrap(a_tag)
    try
        tell application "System Events"
            tell process "Finder"
                tell window "Finder Preferences"
                    tell first scroll area's first table
                        set target_checkbox to first checkbox of first UI element of (first row whose first UI element's name is a_tag)
                        return target_checkbox
                    end tell
                end tell
            end tell
        end tell
    on error
        if seek_error_depth < 5 then
            set seek_error_depth to seek_error_depth + 1
            delay 0.1
            set target_checkbox to seekErrorTrap(a_tag)
            set seek_error_depth to seek_error_depth - 1
            return target_checkbox
        else
            return false
        end if
    end try
end seekErrorTrap
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113570/discussion-on-answer-by-ted-wrigley-programatically-modify-tag-visibility-order). Excellent work on this, so I wanted people to be able to see these comments in chat!

Comment: I missed this coming through a couple years ago - this is bloody AWESOME!  This opens up a whole new world

I'll give it a try tonight.